# Ckan install module missing error

Tags: python, ckan

I am attempting to install ckan on my system and I'm following the install from package directions (http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-from-package.html).  All the dependencies were installed correctly and the ckan package itself downloaded without error.  When I went to run the install I got a module missing error for what to me looks like a trivial python module that should be there.

```
jeremy@jeremy-HP-ProBook-4530s:~$ sudo dpkg -i python-ckan_2.5-trusty_amd64.deb
[sudo] password for jeremy: 
(Reading database ... 214293 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack python-ckan_2.5-trusty_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python-ckan (2.5.1-trusty1) over (2.5.1-trusty1) ...
Setting up python-ckan (2.5.1-trusty1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/paster", line 7, in <module>
    from paste.script.command import run
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import plistlib
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/plistlib.py", line 62, in <module>
    import datetime
ImportError: No module named datetime
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-ckan.postinst: line 18: initctl: command not found
Site datapusher already enabled
```

I've confirmed that datetime is installed with a quick `python -c 'import datetime'` run.  At this point I have done a little bit of digging and haven't been able to find anywhere else where this is duplicated nor exactly how to resolve this.  Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Looking around for the error from plistlib it looks like the same error affecting https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.7/+bug/1368144

Unfortunately I'm not sure how this would have come about.  I'll continue digging and see if I can find out more, but it isn't anything I've seen before but it definitely appears virtualenv related.

Comment: I also found this specifically reference the missing datetime, but with another application on ubuntu also.  Hope it help provide additional documentation to alleviate this bug.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/509283/python-no-module-named-datetime